# How can I create a trigger in PL/SQL that can create a restriction so that they can only put 1 character?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sexo_A
Before update or insert of sexo on ator
for each row 
when (
    if (new.sexo = 'F')
    then
        return 1;
    elseif (new.sexo = 'M')
    then
        return 1;
    else
    then
        return 0;
    end if;)
begin
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR('Só pode meter "F" para feminino e "M" para masculino');
end;
```

What I want to do is to put a restriction when they try to update or insert in the attribute "sexo", and the user can only put the character 'F' (for female) or 'M' (for male).

Comment: This is not the job of the trigger. Use a check constraint instead: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002719

Comment: But that check i use it in the table with the atributes or i have to create a new one?

Comment: By the way, it's `if ... then ... elsif ... then ... end if;` No brackets, no `elseif`. And triggers can't `return` anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the job of the trigger. Use a [check constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002719) instead:

```
ALTER TABLE ator ADD CONSTRAINT ckgender CHECK (sexo IN ('M', 'F'));
```

If you really want to abuse the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sexo
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT OF sexo ON ator
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.sexo NOT IN ('M', 'F'))
    THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Só pode meter "F" para feminino e "M" para masculino');
    END IF;
END trg_sexo;
/
```